# Vue-social-auth not working on messenger and facebook browser

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt for frontend which uses vue-social-auth for social login and laravel for backend which is socialite. It works perfectly well for normal browsers but doesn't work in messanger and Facebook browser. Have anyone come with similar problem.

Any lead is much appreciated.

Comment: The embedded one? Can you show us some visuals of what it looks like when it's working and when it's not?

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved. If anyone faces this problem then please remove vue-social-auth. The problem was that the Facebook and messenger browsers doesn't close the popup given by vue-social-auth and doesn't redirect to the callback.

So the solution would be removing the vue-social-auth package and do it manually on the frontend and in the backend use the socialite stateless method to return JSON response for API calls.